# Firefox fullscreen event not fired

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, fullscreen

I have a div container with a fullscreen toggle button. It's my plugin. When I click that button, Firefox apply to this div a fullscreen mode. It works well, but my container contains links to images, if I click on link the browser show me an image in standard mode, then I press the 'go back' button and I have an issue my container think he's in fullscreen mode yet, I can't catch a fullscreen exist event and refresh my container.
Link for test - http://visitorguide.uk/first-floor-display-area/.

**Solution:**
I've found a solution. Just handle the "visibilitychange" and check if fullscreen mode is enabled or not. If not I recreate a WebGL scene.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Comment: Everything work well except the described situation above.